# Bootstrap sign in button does not redirect to login page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

The button for some reason does not work, it just refreshes the page.
Could someone please provide some information? 
I am new to bootstrap.

The button 'Sign in' is supposed to send action to `$_POST['submit'])` and proceed the login function.
The form data must be sent to the same page.

```php
<?php
if(isLoggedIn()) { redirect(); }

// Login Process
if(check_value($_POST['submit'])) {
    $userLogin = new login();
    $userLogin->validateLogin($_POST['employee_number'], $_POST['password']);
}
?>  
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <small>Sign in</small>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="employee_number" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Employee number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group last">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="submit">Sign in</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```php
/**
 * check_value
 * Looks for valid value and setted ones.
 */
function check_value($value) {
    if((@count($value)>0 and !@empty($value) and @isset($value)) || $value=='0') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you looking for it to do? The reason that it's coming back to the same page is because you told it to do so here: `<form role="form" action="" method="post">`.

Comment: I want $_POST['submit'] to catch the Sign in button :)

Comment: I think the best place for you to start is here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've read it and I still can not find where is the problem. 'Sign in' button is not sending form data.

Comment: @TuteLandželas what's with all of the silencing operators? `@isset` and `@empty` ?

Comment: Security ^_^ is there something wrong? I used the same code with just css template, now that I have implemented bootstrap I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `action` to form.

Right now it will just reload current page - if you provide url there, it will send form to that url (and user will be redirected there).